# Dispatcher View pattern and MVC

Tags: java, oop, model-view-controller, design-patterns, jakarta-ee

I read about the [Dispatcher View pattern](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/DispatcherView.html) and it seems pretty helpful to develop simple web applications.

Can this pattern be considered a simplified MCV or a simple implementation of the MVC pattern?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/

Comment: That question is not about Dispatcher View Pattern :-(

Comment: It was just related, not a dupe or something. The `RequestDispatcher` class is **the** dispatcher part.

Comment: sorry BalusC, I'm not a Java developer and I don't fully understand that code. Anyway it seems it doesn't ask to the question if a front controller that dispatch a request to a view (without an intermediate action controller) and that view that pull its data from a model is or not a kind of MVC

Comment: As I answered, the dispatcher pattern at its own does not necessarily represent MVC. It is however part of MVC. Like as a wheel alone does not necessarily represent a car, but it can however be part of a car.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the [`RequestDispatcher`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) is at its own not necessarily considered a simplified MVC pattern. The forwarded/included JSP in turn can still use *scriptlets* which would then contradict the MVC ideology. Even more, the `RequestDispatcher` can even be used in a JSP (view) instead of a servlet (controller).

But, on the other hand, it is true that the `RequestDispatcher` is been used in the average MVC controller to forward the request/response to a view after doing the business action.

#### See also:

- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - Contains simple Hello World example following basic MVC
- [Design Patterns web based applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/) - Contains detailed answer how to do full MVC